# How can I write lines coming from two lists?

Tags: data-structures, ansible

How can I write lines coming from two lists with Ansible?

Var file: *bottle.yml*

```
Bottle:
 - wine:
   - 1951
   - 1960
 - country_to_export:
   - belgium-1
   - belgium-2
```

*main.yml* file:

```
debug: 
  msg: "I send the bottle {{ item.0 }} to country {{ item.1 }}"
with_items:
 - "{{ Bottle.wine }}"
 - "{{ Bottle.country_to_export}}"
```

Result:

```
"I send the bottle [ u1951, u1960 ] to country [ ubelgium-1,ubelgium-2 ]"
```

---

Desired result:

```
I send the bottle 1951 to country Belgium-1
I send the bottle 1960 to country Belgium-2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just using the wrong type of loop, you should use the loop [`with_together`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/together_lookup.html) instead of the loop `with_items`.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "I send the bottle {{ item.0 }} to country {{ item.1 }}"
      with_together:
      - "{{ Bottle.wine }}"
      - "{{ Bottle.country_to_export}}"

      vars:
        Bottle:
          wine:
            - 1951
            - 1960
          country_to_export:
            - belgium-1
            - belgium-2
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1951, 'belgium-1']) => {
    "msg": "I send the bottle 1951 to country belgium-1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[1960, 'belgium-2']) => {
    "msg": "I send the bottle 1960 to country belgium-2"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Also mind that in your given *bottle.yml*, your dictionary is wrong, compared to what you says it is giving you.
It should rather be:

```yaml
Bottle:
  wine:
    - 1951
    - 1960
  country_to_export:
    - belgium-1
    - belgium-2
```

---

A better syntax, if you want to be compatible with upcoming versions of Ansible is to drop the `with_*` structure and start to use their [`loop` replacement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-together).

So the above playbook will end up being:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: "I send the bottle {{ item.0 }} to country {{ item.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ Bottle.wine | zip(Bottle.country_to_export) | list }}"

      vars:
        Bottle:
          wine:
            - 1951
            - 1960
          country_to_export:
            - belgium-1
            - belgium-2
```

Yielding the same recap.